# View constrained to outside of ConstraintLayout doesn't receive touch events

Tags: android, imageview, android-constraintlayout, android-touch-event

I have an image view which is constrained to outside of it's parent ConstraintLayout with `clipChildren` set to false on the parent layout.

The problem is that the image when outside the constraint layout does not receive any touch events (see code below to reproduce).

As soon as I change the constraints on the image view to be within the parent constraint layout, it works as expected.

Is there any way I can get this to work?

I am using ConstraintLayout v1.1.3

[image: Problem demonstration]

**MainActivity.kt**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

        image.setOnClickListener {
            it.background = getDrawable(R.color.colorPrimaryDark)
        }
    }
}
```

**content_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipChildren="false">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="400dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"/>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Means are you saying you have to use 2 constraintlayout for imageview?

Comment: No I’m saying, anytime you constrain a views top to the bottom of its parent ConstraintLayout, it stops receiving on touch events

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score -3):

Well, instead of an ImageView, a good option here would be to use an ImageButton.
You can easily initialise it and set an on click listener :

```
ImageButton img = (ImageButton)findViewbyId(R.id.image)
// This is java code.
```

And, then set an OnClickListener.

Edit:- Ok, I understood your point.
The basic fact is that negative margins are NOT accepted in constraint layout.
That's why it isn't receiving touch events.
You should constrain it in an another way.

Comment: An image button has the same problem when constrained in the same manner as the question describes

Comment: I’m not using negative margins, im actually using an alternative solution to negative margins: https://medium.com/@jemli.idea/constraintlayout-never-ever-97c121286100#52b4